# Extracting url from string in C

Tags: c, regex

How can i extract urls from a string in C?

Say we have "bla bla bla bla bla blaaa http://www.stackoverflow.com blaaa bllaaa"

i want to pass that link to a varible.

How can i do that?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you need to copy the bytes or a pointer to the URL is enough?

Comment: Wanna pass it to a variable, so i think i need to copy.

Comment: You need to copy if you want to overwrite the initial string (reading data from a stream in a loop for example) or if you need to change it (to "https://..."); you don't need to copy if you just want to print it, or count domains, or ...

Comment: Homework? It would help if you added your attempt ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Search for `"http://"` using `strstr`
   function.
2. Starting for this pointer stop on first null or space, if space set on this position null.
3. Now you pointer resulted in step 1, pointing to your url.

Comment: @wonnie: And if a copy is needed ... once you have the pointer and the terminating null in place, just call `strcpy`. Make sure you have enough space! (+1)